# Computing the week for a certain date

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query that computes for every date the week it falls in (a week begins on Sunday and ends on Saturday):

```
SELECT EntryDate
      ,CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS DATE) AS 'SundayDate'
      ,CAST(DATEADD(DAY ,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS DATE) AS 'SaturdayDate'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY ,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate), 103) + ' - ' +
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY ,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate), 103) AS 'Week'
FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS DATE) <=
      CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS DATE)
```

It works fine, but I don't like the repeated function calls because they cluster the query and make it less readable.

How can I make the query cleaner and more readable? (I'm using SQL Server 2008.)

Comment: I am not sure that you can make this "cleaner" or more readable.  it looks pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT EntryDate
         , DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS SundayDate
         , DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS SaturdayDate
        FROM MyTable
), Coming AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS Sunday
)
SELECT EntryDate
     , SundayDate
     , SaturdayDate
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR, SundayDate, 103) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SaturdayDate, 103) AS Week
    FROM Dates, Coming
    WHERE SundayDate <= Coming.Sunday
    ORDER BY 2;
```

The simplifications I've made are:

- Extracted most of the query into a Common Table Expression named `Dates` to reduce redundancy.
- Removed the pointless `CAST(... AS DATE)`, since `DATEADD()` already produces dates.
- Used a column number for `ORDER BY`.  With the Common Table Expression, though, we could just as easily `ORDER BY SundayDate`.
- Extracted `DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())` into a Common Table Expression named `Coming`.  This doesn't reduce the complexity of the query, but helps make the WHERE-clause read more like English.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf783/8)

---

#### Edit

Since the benefits of the last two suggestions are debatable, you may prefer a milder approach that incorporates just the first two suggestions:

```
WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT EntryDate
         , DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS SundayDate
         , DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS SaturdayDate
        FROM MyTable
)
SELECT EntryDate
     , SundayDate
     , SaturdayDate
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR, SundayDate, 103) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SaturdayDate, 103) AS Week
    FROM Dates
    WHERE SundayDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
    ORDER BY SundayDate;
```

Comment: what are you doing?  can you elaborate on this answer?  I am  a little lost myself.

Comment: @Malachi Sorry, the previous revision didn't actually work with SQL Server. I've edited it into a proper answer now.

Comment: I don't like it, but it is functional.  personally I like my query better than this one. your Query and mine have the exact same Execution plan. :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf783/11

Comment: @Malachi The `Coming` CTE might be a bit excessive; you can easily undo that part if you prefer.

Comment: you would have to change the Query completely.  I think that with out that `Coming` CTE you might have to do it the other way....not positive though.

Comment: @Malachi It's not that hard to remove the `Coming` CTE.

Comment: oh I see now.  I was skimming, I really have to learn not to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can lose the `CAST` that surrounds the `DATEADD` function.

The `DATEADD` function should spit out a `DATETIME` datatype.

It should look like this:

```
SELECT EntryDate
  ,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS 'SundayDate'
  ,DATEADD(DAY ,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS 'SaturdayDate'
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY ,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate), 103) + ' - ' +
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY ,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate), 103) AS 'Week'
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate)  <=
      DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate)
```

In the `ORDER BY` statement you might be able to use the Alias from your `SELECT` Statement, which would really speed this up.

```
SELECT EntryDate
  ,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS 'SundayDate'
  ,DATEADD(DAY ,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate) AS 'SaturdayDate'
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY ,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate), 103) + ' - ' +
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY ,7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate), 103) AS 'Week'
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EntryDate), EntryDate)  <=
      DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY 'Sunday_Date`
```

I would put `DESC` on that order by because I would want the newest dates to show up first, **if you are grabbing dates from the past**

**If you are grabbing from the future**, then you would want 'ASC' in there, but that is default.

I Can't remember who said it but

> it is as simple as it can be when there is nothing left that can be taken away

Comment: OUCH!! MY EYES BLEED!! (that's just me I guess)

Comment: @retailcoder, unfortunately, when you use a function in the `SELECT` and give it an alias, you can't just use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, you have to calculate it again. the `ORDER BY` the OP Might be able to use the alias...

Comment: I meant all these caps aren't making it an easy read imho :)

Comment: that is the coding syntax of SQL,  most of the SQL engines are not case sensitive on these keywords though.  but it makes it easier to pick them out when the code gets bigger, @retailcoder

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately `CAST` is necessary here because only the date part is needed; the time part should be omitted. But I did use an alias in the `ORDER BY` clause, I didn't notice it was possible to do it (unlike in the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: @kodkod, if you need the date without the time part for reporting purposes, that should be done on the report side not on the database side. that should speed things up a little bit, because that is less functions running in the query.  the reporting software would be able to do it easier I think.